# Total number of palindromic subsequences in a string

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

The question is like this--

For every string given as input, you need to tell the number of subsequences of it that are palindromes (need not necessarily be distinct). Note that the empty string is not a palindrome.
For example, the palindromic subsequences of "aab" are:

"a", "a", "b", "aa", and the method returns 4.

I had the Dynamic Programming solution to finding Longest Palindromic Subsequence in mind and therefore tried to take ideas from it. Couldn't really get the solution. May be dynamic programming is not even required. Suggestions please.

And there is one more catch. When the condition "need not necessarily be distinct" is removed, can we still count without actually generating all the palindromic subsequences?

Comment: What is the answer for `aba`? Do you really mean subsequences, or substrings?

Comment: I mean subsequences only. Answer for "aba" is 'a', 'b', 'a', 'aa','aba' i.e 5. As you can see, 'aa' is actually a subsequence and not a substring.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-strings-find-first-string-subsequence-second/     this can help you to find if str1 is subsequence of str2 or not and then run this to check for every part of the string

Comment: @therealprashant I am sorry but how does that help? We have to count the number of palindromic subsequences and what would be the space and time complexity of the method that you are suggesting?

Comment: Instead of finding the longest sequence only, keep in memory all the palindromes found and the subsequences of each palindrome

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[EDIT 19/10/2015: An anonymous reviewer pointed out a problem with the formula, which prompted me to notice another, even bigger mistake...  Now fixed.]**

I now see how to drop the solution time down to **O(n^2)**.  I'll leave my other answer up in case it's interesting as a stepping-stone to this one.  Note: This is (also) only a solution to the first part of the problem; I see no way to efficiently count only *distinct* palindromic subsequences (PS).

Instead of counting the number of PS that begin and end at exactly the positions i and j, let's count how many begin at *or after* i and end at *or before* j.  Call this g(i, j).

We can try to write g(i, j) = g(i, j-1) + g(i+1, j) + (x[i] == x[j])*g(i+1, j-1) for the case when j > i.  But this doesn't quite work, because the first two terms will double-count any PS that begin *after* i and end *before* j.

The key insight is to notice that we can easily calculate the number of PS that begin or end at some *exact* position by subtracting off other values of g(), and perhaps adding yet more values of g() back on to compensate for double-counting.  For example, the number of PS that begin at *exactly* i and end at *exactly* j is g(i, j) - g(i+1, j) - g(i, j-1) + g(i+1, j-1): the last term corrects for the fact that both the second and third terms count all g(i+1, j-1) PS that begin *after* i and end *before* j.

Every PS that begins at or after i and ends at or before j is in exactly 1 of 4 categories:

1. It begins after i, and ends before j.
2. It begins at i, and ends before j.
3. It begins after i, and ends at j.
4. It begins at i, and ends at j.

g(i+1, j) counts all PS in category 1 or 3, and g(i, j-1) counts all PS in category 1 or 2, so their sum g(i+1, j) + g(i, j-1) counts all PS in category 2 or 3 once each, and all PS in category 1 twice.  Since g(i+1, j-1) counts all PS in category 1 only, subtracting this off to get g(i+1, j) + g(i, j-1) - g(i+1, j-1) gives the total number of PS in category 1, 2 and 3.  The remaining PS are those in category 4.  If x[i] != x[j] then there are no PS in this category; otherwise, there are exactly as many as there are PS that begin at or after i+1 and end at or before j-1, namely g(i+1, j-1), plus one extra for the 2-character sequence x[i]x[j].  **[EDIT: Thanks to commenter Tuxdude for 2 fixes here!]**

With this in hand, we can express g() in a way that changes the quadratic case from f() to constant time:

```
g(i, i) = 1 (i.e. when j = i)
g(i, i+1) = 2 + (x[i] == x[i+1]) (i.e. 3 iff adjacent chars are identical, otherwise 2)
g(i, j) = 0 when j < i (this new boundary case is needed)
g(i, j) = g(i+1, j) + g(i, j-1) - g(i+1, j-1) + (x[i] == x[j])*(g(i+1, j-1)+1) when j >= i+2
```

The final answer is now simply g(1, n).

Comment: How did you come to the definition of g(i,j)? It isn't very intuitive.

Comment: I think it is.  It's the same as the definition of f(i, j), except we relax the *requirement* that positions i and j be in the PS.  f(i, j) is the number of PS that begin at i and end at j; g(i, j) is the number contained somewhere in the range x[i .. j].

Comment: Also shouldn't `g(i, i + 1)` be either `2` `(iff x[i] != x[i+1])` or `3` `(iff x[i] == x[i+1])` ?

Comment: I re-thought about your Solution with an example - `aaa`. The correct result should be 7, but as per your calculation it will only be 6. On looking at the approach once again, there is error when you calculate the additional sum for the `exactly starting at and exactly ending at` part. I feel you're over-complicating this calculation. You should instead be using just  `g(i + 1, j -1) + 1` for this part. The `1` is required for the PS obtained by using just the chars `x[i]` and `x[j]`.

Comment: @Tuxdude: Thanks!  You're absolutely right on both counts.  In the latter case I wasn't simply overcomplicating the calculation, but definitely calculating the wrong thing.  I've now edited.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I still see that you've left the `+1` part I mentioned. You need to account for one additional PS obtained by using just the characters x[i] and x[j] concatenated together, (which will be a PS since x[i] == x[j]). The last line of the recursion relation should state: `g(i, j) = g(i+1, j) + g(i, j-1) - g(i+1, j-1) + (x[i] == x[j])*(g(i+1, j-1) + 1) when j >= i+2`

Comment: @Tuxdude: Thanks, sorry about that!  I really appreciate the attention you've given this, hopefully everything is now correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a horrible O(n^4) solution:

Every palindromic subsequence begins at some position i and ends at some position j >= i such that x[i] = x[j], and its "interior" (all characters except the first and last) is either empty or a palindromic subsequence of x[i+1 .. j-1].

So we can define f(i, j) to be the number of palindromic subsequences beginning at i and ending at j >= i.  Then

```
f(i, j) = 0 if x[i] != x[j]
f(i, i) = 1 (i.e. when j = i)
f(i, j) = 1 + the sum of f(i', j') over all i < i' <= j' < j otherwise
```

**[EDIT: Fixed to count palindromic subsequences of length <= 2 too!]**

Then the final answer is the sum of f(i, j) over all 1 <= i <= j <= n.

The DP for this is O(n^4) because there are n^2 table entries, and computing each one takes O(n^2) time.  (It's probably possible to speed this up to at least O(n^3) by making use of the fact that x[i] != x[j] implies f(i, j) = 0.)

Comment: I am not exactly getting your solution. Can you please run it on "aab"? Also, can you please take a look at the 2nd part of the question?

Comment: f(i,j) = ?? if x[i] == x[j]

Comment: On "aab", we get f(1, 1) = f(2, 2) = f(3, 3) = 1, f(1, 2) = 1 + 0 (because x[1] = x[2]), f(2, 3) = 0 (because x[2] != x[3]), f(1, 3) = 0 (because x[1] != x[3]).  Total: 1+1+1+1+0+0 = 4.  (Note: I edited the answer to fix a bug.)

Comment: The second part of the question seems much harder, or at least I can't think of a way to tackle it efficiently.

Comment: Regarding "f(i,j) = ?? if x[i] == x[j]": The idea is that the 3 cases listed are tried in order, and as soon as one's conditions are satisfied it is considered a match.  So if x[i] == x[j] then case 1's condition fails, so we try case 2.  If i == j then we immediately match case 2 and return 1; otherwise, we drop through to case 3.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitive O(n^3) solution using DP:

Let each state dp(i,j) represents number of palindromic subsequences in string[i...j]
Then simple recursive formula is

```
for k in range i, j-1:
    if(A[j]==A[k]){
        dp(i,j) = dp(i,j) + dp(k+1,j-1);
```

The Idea is very simple.. For adding a new character check if it is end of a subsequence or not. If there exist same character in the previously computed smaller subproblem, then it add the number of subsequences contained in range (k+1,j-1).
Just take care of corner cases.
Add one as newly added character is a single character subsequence too.
Even if there are no subsequences in the range (k+1,j-1) , you would still get 1 new subsequences of length 2 (like "aa").