# Count Different Palindromic Subsequences

Tags: algorithm, palindrome, subsequence

[Source Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-different-palindromic-subsequences/description/)

Given a string S, find the number of different non-empty palindromic subsequences in S, and return that number modulo 10^9 + 7.

A subsequence of a string S is obtained by deleting 0 or more characters from S.

A sequence is palindromic if it is equal to the sequence reversed.

Two sequences A_1, A_2, ... and B_1, B_2, ... are different if there is some i for which A_i != B_i.

Example 1:
Input: 
S = 'bccb'

Output: 6

Explanation: 
The 6 different non-empty palindromic subsequences are 'b', 'c', 'bb', 'cc', 'bcb', 'bccb'.

Note that 'bcb' is counted only once, even though it occurs twice.

**Sol 1.** Given Solution [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-different-palindromic-subsequences/solution/), it looks quite unintuitive

**Sol 2.** The Other solution which I do understand is to find all palindromic subsequence and use set to keep it distinct but output can be very large and keeping them in the set is not good Idea I think.([here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-palindromic-subsequence-given-string/))

**Is there any better and intuitive approach to solve this problem?**

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853952/total-number-of-palindromic-subsequences-in-a-string?rq=1)